# How to animate the height of a box depending to the content inside?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

It should be simple, but I can't find how.
In this exemple, when adding or removing a new item, i would like to the the #app height change smoothly, instead of instantanly.

In pure css

Thanks for help.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-frog-qfy64

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
    <button @click="removeItem">Remove</button>
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" class="box" :key="i">BOX</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    items: [1, 1]
  }),
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push(1);
    },
    removeItem() {
      this.items.pop();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: blue;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.box {
  padding: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try adding the animate function using JS instead of CSS, here is a link [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

Comment: You could compute the height of the app component based on the items and set to that height  to app DOM. https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-field-vj9xo

Comment: Yes i've found out how in JS, but i'm surprised there is no way in css
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-frog-qfy64

Answer (score 0):

You need a measurement unit for it to be animated. `height: auto` won't do it.

You will need to compute the items height in JS.

Comment: Yes i've found out how in JS, but i'm surprised there is no way in css
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-frog-qfy64